# How to go to previous screen from an activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a class  TestFragment which extends Fragment,from this Fragment I have started Activity1

and from Activity1 i have started Activity2,Now i am in Activity2 want to go to TestFragment

when a button inside Activity2 is clicked and i want to update the UI in TestFragment

Comment: Just finish this activiy. this.finish()

Answer (score 1):

Call `finish()` if you want to go back to the *caller* activity. If you want to launch the activity which contains the fragment create an intent and launch the activity, something like `startActivity(new Intent(this,youractivity.class));`

Comment: sorry to say and i want to update the UI in TestFragment

Comment: You'll need to be more specific that this to get any help

Comment: How can i use startActivity as i want to go to Fragment class

Answer (score 1):

Please write some code..Anyway if you want start another activity take a look here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html onClick event you just put the intent for example `Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestFragment.class);`

Comment: How can i use startActivity as i want to go to TestFragment class

Comment: In which sense? just do something like: `Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestFragment.class);` and then `startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 1):

you can clear the stack activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

by this code you will clear the stack and MainActivity will be opend.
Hope this help you